# Empty value of EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I am making an app designed to convert lengths in different units. Let's say you want to convert 2 meters into centimeters. You'll have to enter the value in an EditText which's inputType is numberDecimal, then choose meter in a spinner, then choosing to convert it to centimeters in another spinner. I wanted to make the app fully automated and decided to add a TextWatcher. Problem is when you delete everything in the EditText, it obviously can't multiply or divide by nothing (not 0, nothing) and execute the methods, and so it crashed the app. Is there any solution to the problem? I have tried this, but it still crashed:

```
final EditText lengthEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterLength); 
lengthEntry.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
final EditText lengthEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterLength);
    lengthEntry.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (Double.valueOf(lengthEntry.getText().toString()) == ""){} else {
                lengthConverter();
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is the logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: n1.theconverter, PID: 5585
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
   at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
   at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
   at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
   at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:338)
   at n1.theconverter.MainActivity$3.afterTextChanged(MainActivity.java:87)
   at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:8007)
   at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:10168)
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1043)
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:560)
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:225)
   at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:224)
   at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.deleteSurroundingText(BaseInputConnection.java:244)
   at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:389)
   at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Thank you in advance :)

edit: new logcat:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
                                                                 at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
                                                                 at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
                                                                 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
                                                                 at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:338)
                                                                 at n1.theconverter.MainActivity.lengthConverter(MainActivity.java:176)
                                                                 at n1.theconverter.MainActivity$3.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:91)
                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7991)
                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:8053)
                                                                 at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:10157)
                                                                 at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1033)
                                                                 at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:559)
                                                                 at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:225)
                                                                 at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:224)
                                                                 at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspaceOrForwardDelete(BaseKeyListener.java:106)
                                                                 at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspace(BaseKeyListener.java:51)
                                                                 at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.onKeyDown(BaseKeyListener.java:215)
                                                                 at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:138)
                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:6098)
                                                                 at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5911)
                                                                 at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2640)
                                                                 at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:9234)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2395)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1727)
                                                                 at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2725)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:541)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:319)
                                                                 at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
                                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2310)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4127)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4089)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forwa
04-19 20:38:03.451 6053-6053/n1.theconverter D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                                           --------- 
beginning of crash
04-19 20:38:03.451 6053-6053/n1.theconverter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                           Process: n1.theconverter, PID: 6053
                                                           java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
                                                               at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
                                                               at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
                                                               at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
                                                               at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:338)
                                                               at n1.theconverter.MainActivity.lengthConverter(MainActivity.java:176)
                                                               at n1.theconverter.MainActivity$3.onTextChanged(MainActivity.java:91)
                                                               at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7991)
                                                               at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:8053)
                                                               at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:10157)
                                                               at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1033)
                                                               at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:559)
                                                               at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:225)
                                                               at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.delete(SpannableStringBuilder.java:224)
                                                               at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspaceOrForwardDelete(BaseKeyListener.java:106)
                                                               at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.backspace(BaseKeyListener.java:51)
                                                               at android.text.method.BaseKeyListener.onKeyDown(BaseKeyListener.java:215)
                                                               at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:138)
                                                               at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:6098)
                                                               at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:5911)
                                                               at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2640)
                                                               at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:9234)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2395)
                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1727)
                                                               at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2725)
                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:541)
                                                               at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:319)
                                                               at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2310)
                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4127)
                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4089)
                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem. The boolean in the `if` method was incorrect. Here is the correct way to do it with the `isEmpty()` method:

```
if (lengthEntry.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
    tvAnswer.setText("0.0");
} else {
    lengthConverter();
}
```

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

You can not compare an **empty string** with `Double` value. Still you can check if `editText` has got any value: if yes, then call your calculation method. Try this:

```
 private EditText lengthEntry;    //Declare globally

 lengthEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterLength); 
 lengthEntry.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
 @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (!lengthEntry.getText().toString().equals("")){
               lengthConverter();
            } 
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still crashing ?? Can you show the error log please ? This must not be the same as above.

Comment: I think it is still executing lengthConverter() because I get the same error (Invalid double: ""). I was thinking maybe the default value (when there is no text) isn't "" , but something else.

Comment: `lengthEntry.getText().toString().equals("")` means that your `editText` is empty. You are not passing your `editText` value to `lengthConverter()` or not assigning to any global variable which might be changed. So, if `lengthConverter()` is causing the error then it may not be related to `editText` value.

Answer (score 0):

I would do 2 things here:
First make sure THE LENGTH > 0.  The second is check to make sure that it is indeed changable.  e.g. not just '-' or '.'.  But something like -#.#

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `lengthEntry` have the proper id of the input field. and you can try `System.out.println();`to see the lenght and input.

And try to parse the value by `Doube.parseDouble(lenghtEntry.getText().toString());`.

Had this same issue and ID wasn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition, your `onTextChange` should look like:

```
@Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s.equals(""){
            lengthEntry.setText("0");
        } else {
            lengthConverter();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Try again, I add a default value, if that doesn't work maybe the problem is in your `lengthConverter();` method.